# How to specify the production server address at build for a Meteor app?

Tags: meteor

My app still tries to connect to my local server 192.x.x.x instead of the URL I put in the command line: `../directory --server myserverprod.com:8080`

Do I miss any option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it with an environment variable

```
export ROOT_URL=myserverprod.com:8080
```

Comment: Thx you. But my question is in incomplete I was talking about the client cordova app still trying to connect to my local server. I will post a more specific question.